# Usage of Async await with hooks

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, async-await, asynccallback

I have a simple translation function that takes one parameter(string) and return string. It works fine when i use like `await translation(key)` how ever my need it to use it frequently inside in react native component like below

```
<Text>{tranlate("faqs")}</Text>
```

Then again somewhere

```
<Button title={translate("terms")}/>
```

My question is although its a async function and not trigger without await or then/catch block. What could be other way i can simple use it without await or then/catch because using it like below is not working

```
<Text>{await translate("faqs")}</Text>
```

Any help would be really appriciated!Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to create a custom hook which takes `key` as input and return translated key.

You shouldn't use `async-await` in `(J|T)SX`.

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/modern-night-hqt7n3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A32%2C1)

> So it can also be used in multiple components

```
const _cache = {};

function useTranslate(key) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(key);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        // IF PROMISE RESOLVED THEN GET TRANSLATED VALUE
        const cachedValue = _cache[key];
        if (!cachedValue) {
          const translatedValue = await translate(key);
          _cache[key] = translatedValue;
          setState(translatedValue);
        } else setState(cachedValue);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })();
  }, [key]);

  // IF VALUE IS TRANSLATED THEN IT WILL RETURN VALUE
  // ELSE RETURN KEY AS A FALLBACK VALUE
  return state;
}

export default function App() {
  const translateFAQ = useTranslate("faqs");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Text>{translateFAQ}</Text>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: perfectly work, now i want to improve it little more, for example if same key is fetch multiple times can we memorize is some how ? like using useMemo hook ? so that we can avoid duplicate requests to translate function. @DecPK Would you please suggest way? Thanks

Comment: @AliAkram Added cached value snippet. Sandbox also updated

Comment: this works but can we use useMemo hook for this purpose and expose one function "t" like this below code

` const useTranslized = () => {
   const t = async (key: string) => {
     try {
       return await translate(key);
     } catch (error) {
       return "";
     }
   };

   const memoizedTranslate = useMemo(() => t, []);

   return {
     t2: memoizedTranslate,
   };
 };`

Comment: what is the difference here. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: You are memoizing a function and I'm memoizing a value

Comment: I want to achieve caching via useMemo within the same solution you shared.

Comment: But why, We are already caching value in `_cache` object

Comment: okay @DecPK Perfect, Thanks a lot

Comment: I have one little issue, that when i use useTranslate("somekey") and i put console log inside useEffect block then i observed its being called multiple times against a single call. Do you think there is some issue in above you shared? Many thanks

Comment: Not a problem, If you are using `useMultiple` hook multiple times then that is absolutely fine

Comment: yes but for one one time usage it should print one console, it prints 2-3 times for one single usage

Comment: @AliAkram Can you show me your code, in any online codesandbox. Wihtout looking at code it is hard to imagine

Comment: I have put code [here](https://paste-bin.xyz/8110726) and getting this error 
`rendered more hooks than during the previous render`

Comment: DecPK
  can please check this is bit urgent. Thanks

Comment: @AliAkram Link is expired. Can you add it again

Comment: This error `rendered more hooks than during the previous render` means you are using conditionals with hooks which break one of hook rules (`Only Call Hooks at the Top Level `)

Comment: I got your point so for example I have couple of places with in my JSX where this translation is need, what approach do you suggest ? Should I declare all needed translation hooks on top on my component and then use below ? Many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple custom hook that will return you the translated text:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Your translate function
const translate = async (str) => {
  return str;
};

export const useTranslate = (str) => {
  const [translatedText, setTranslatedText] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTranslation = async () => {
      const result = await translate(str);
      setTranslatedText(result);
    };

    getTranslation();
  }, [str]);

  return translatedText;
};
```

This can then be consumed in a component like this:

```js
const translatedText = useTranslate('abc')

return (
  <Text>{translatedText}</Text>
)
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and mine. It is almost same

Comment: We both were writing it at the same time :)

Comment: thanks @AliNauman this is also good solution, thanks for help.